# Fastest Leveling BFBC2

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

What is the fastest way to level up in Battlefield Bad Company 2 on PC? 
Which kit usually yields the most points per minute?

Answer (score 7):

Medic is generally the fastest. Some people have actually complained about it on the official forums and requested a nerf for gameplay balance. Speaking as someone who primarily plays recon, though, I think it's fine.

**Non-Medic-Specific Notes**

Below are a bunch of notes about level the Medic class, but here are a few for any class.

- *Try to find nearly-full servers.* When there are a few people on a map, it takes a long time to find each other. It also takes a long time to end the round, which is when you get a pile of bonus points for special actions. I prefer lightly-loaded servers, but it clearly hurts my points-per-minute.
- *Understand bonus points.* From the main game screen, explore Multiplayer > Weapons and Gadgets, and Multiplayer > My Stats. These show how you're doing on progress toward various awards, as well as stars for accomplishments on various weapons. Some of these awards will give 5,000 to 10,000 bonus points.
- *Follow (and set) waypoints.* If one of the objectives is marked with pointy things around it, go there. Not only is this good gameplay, concentrating your squad's resources on a given objective, but it also generates points for you and your team when you capture or defend the point, as well as bonuses at the end of the round if you do it enough. It disappoints me that people don't do this more. If no one on your squad has set a waypoint, point your weapon at an objective and use your spotting key to highlight it.

**Medics: Points**

Kyle's list of points is correct, though I can confirm it's 20 points for a squad heal. So you can see the big points are to be had through revives, which not only get you points but win back tickets for your team, extending your chances of winning.

**Watch for Opportunities**

Assuming you're not playing hardcore (which has no minimap): when a teammate dies, you'll see a white defibrillator line on the map; when a squadmate dies it'll be bright green. Force yourself to keep watching the minimap until you're always aware of people needing revives nearby.

As I recall you also see a white bandaid icon flickering above people in need of a heal, and a white cross on the map for people who have specifically requested healing.

**Leveling Medics: The Dark Side**

I've often been the victim of a medic who was either reviving without thinking, or was playing for points without regard for the team.

If someone goes down in a barrage of fire you can revive them, often from partial cover, then run back into hiding to heal yourself... and watch your "patient" get killed in the same killzone where they died just a moment before. This makes points for you, and doesn't hurt your team's tickets, but it counts as a death for your patient (besides cheesing them off... especially if you do it a second time).

I've seen some medics do this in a major massacre, racking up points but not really helping the team. Some might disagree, and it's always context-dependent, but I feel at a certain point you just become a ghoul, gathering points from victims' dead bodies. Sometimes you need to let people die so they can fall back, resupply, and regroup.

So think before you rez.

**Leveling Medics: The Light Side**

Dropping a healing crate in a killzone, though, is perfectly fair, and much appreciated. Then you're not being a ghoul, you're keeping people from being dead.

When I play medic I always go for the extended range perk, which doubles the radius of your healing pack. This is another win-win: it'll greatly boost your points, and really helps your team.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the Dark Side of Medic revives. I've started calling this the "Heroic Medic Problem". Very few things will upset your teammates more than continually reviving them in the middle of a massacre that they have no time to react to before being killed again.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation on +20. I had a terrible round once with an idiot medic before the TK limit went up to -100 and -25. The guy literally killed me, rezzed me, killed me, rezzed me, rinse and repeat for 10 mins. Was great fun.

Comment: Play in servers with no tanks.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely the Medic. Once you have earned both the Med-kit and Defibrillator then you start to eat levels up.

Play in a squad and then the points will get even better. If I'm not mistaken, you'll get:

- 30 Points per Squad Heal (might be 20?)
- 80 Points per Squad Revive
- 10 Points per normal heal
- 50 Points per normal revive

This leads to a lot of points very quickly, and mixed in with taking some flags and the odd kill here and there and you will gain levels very fast.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the Medic works quite well when you've gained the medkit and ability to heal other players and defib them. Be aware of enemy fire and heal your teammates quickly and drop medkits plentiful. The LMG's that go with the medic also have stopping power, allowing you to drop enemies fast.

Answer (score 0):

The engineer is pretty good as well, if you stay with tanks/vehicles and keep repairing them when they get damaged you can rack up quite a healthy lead, especially if the person in the vehicle is on your squad.

Also on defense if you equip the mines and lay them at key road points (where you would normally expect the enemy to come down in a tank or jeep) you can rack up a healthy points/kills bonus there too.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others that playing as medic brings lots of points, but don't overlook the use of different weapons. With each weapon you try, you'll progress from getting a small number of points to thousands of points for the top skill levels. The awards are granted on the basis of the number of kills you get, so with all the different weapons there are tens of thousands of points to be earned just by switching up weapons and trying different things.

And be sure to focus on class abilities, particularly in squads as another suggested. When playing assault, be sure to toss lots of ammo packs. Your teammates will appreciate it, and you'll get points. As a medic, throw health. As an engineer be sure to repair vehicles. And as a recon, be sure to chuck sensors to reveal enemies. This is particularly effective when playing the "Rush" game mode. As soon as an MCOM has a charge planted, throw a sensor near it and you'll get points for all the attackers it detects when they're killed. You can rack up a *lot* of points that way.

Answer (score 0):

I play engineer and recon the most i find it easier to level up using recon with more points per kill with headshots and spoting but you get more kills with the engineer and you can repair vehicles. Overall though i do find engineer the funest to play